# parametric equations multivariate calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

could anyone help me to solve this problem

Given a parametrization of the tangent line to the curve,(x(t),y(t))

at t=a is:

```
       x(a)+tx'(a)

       y(a)+ty'(a)
```

Also given that the equation of the tangent line at x=a to y=f(x) is

```
      y=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)
```

How does this equation relate to the parametric equation above.

I believe that i muse substitute something from this equation to the one above but i dont know how to do so. And i tried drawing a graph f(x) with the equation of a tangent line to the equation on the point (x(t),y(t)). Could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point would be to recognize that: $f'(a) = \dfrac{dy}{dx}|_{x=a} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}_{t=a} = \dfrac{y'(a)}{x'(a)}$. Then you can rewrite the tangent equation as: $\dfrac{y-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a) = \dfrac{y'(a)}{x'(a)}$, and this gives: $\dfrac{y-f(a)}{y'(a)} = \dfrac{x-a}{x'(a)} = t$. From this you get the two equations in $t$. This shows you can deduce the standard equation of the tangent line  from the parametric equations.